# This should calculate how long it takes for an investment to double. Return values are way too long. I am required to use a while loop

Tags: python

This program is meant to get input from the user, initial investment and apy and is meant to return the number of years it takes for the investment to double. I've been testing 100 for the principal and .05 for the apy but the result I'm getting is over 14,000 years. This value should calculate to a little over 15 years. I can seem to find the issue and could use some pointers.

```
def main():
    print("This program calculates the amount of time it takes for an investment to double")
    principal = eval(input("What is the initial investment amount? "))
    apy = eval(input("What is the annual interest rate? "))
    years = 0

    while principal < (2 * principal):
        principal = principal * (1 + apy)
        years = years + 1
    print("It will take", years, "years for your investment to double." )
main()
```

Comment: `principal < (2 * principal)` This will always be true.

Comment: @tkausl No, only until they reach infinity.

Comment: _I don't see how principal < (2*principal) will always be true_ You don't see how x must be less than 2x?  Okay...

Comment: @JohnGordon I don't see it, either. Because it's not true.

Comment: @KellyBundy Assuming principal is greater than zero, how could it ever not be true?

Comment: @JohnGordon I already said it in my comment above yours.

Comment: @JohnGordon is right, it will be in loop forever.
Even if principal becomes 100, 200 , 300 or a billion. It will always be less than 2*principal as 2 billion is > billion and 600 > 300 , 400 > 200 and so on...

Comment: @GokulGarre No they're not right, as I already explained and as the OP's result 14000 proves.

Comment: @KellyBundy The loop eventually stopped because 2* principal _overflowed_, right?   Overflow is not the same as infinity.

Comment: @KellyBundy try running the same code in an online compiler with a print statement inside while, you will understand!
You will get a result but the print in while will run forever.

Try running it and check it out

Comment: @GokulGarre You should do that yourself. I've already done that (well, only printed *after* the loop, no point printing *inside*).

Comment: @JohnGordon Overflow of floats gets you infinity. Are you thinking of fixed-size ints?

Comment: @KellyBundy I was thinking of integers.  That explains it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

when you increase the pricipal in every loop you also increase 2 times principal

as `x+1 < (x+1)* 2`

And you have your infinite loop in at least theory

But python stops at ∞  < 2 * ∞ and that is correct as 2 * ∞  Is ∞ and makes the equation false and ends the loop

Add another variable.

```
def main():
    print("This program calculates the amount of time it takes for an investment to double")
    principal = eval(input("What is the initial investment amount? "))
    apy = eval(input("What is the annual interest rate? "))
    years = 0
    resultinv = principal
    while resultinv < (2 * principal):
        resultinv = resultinv * (1 + apy)
        years = years + 1
    print("It will take", years, "years for your investment to double." )
main()
```

Comment: "when you increase the pricipal in every loop you also increase 2 times principa" - that makes sence thank you